# where is csharp source code is used sharepoint

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

please provide the csharp area in sharepoint. what are the part csharp source  is used. how can be document loaded in the sharepoint. whether it can be done through by c sharp.

Comment: Very ambiguous question - SharePoint is build on the .Net framework and from a developer point of view there are a vast number of SharePoint functionalities that can be extended/leveraged using the .Net framework. The most common items would be WebParts, EventHandlers and Workflows.

Comment: http://plzsendmethecode.blogspot.com/

Comment: I think the author actually wanted to know how to inject C# code into sharepoint to do custom stuff. Well you may search for SharePoint features to find that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost everything on SP is built into assemblies, so you can't see the C# source. You can use a tool like [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to disassemble these assemblies (but they could be obfuscated).

If you want to upload documents through C# have a look at the WebServices. [Here's a pretty good tutorial](http://geek.hubkey.com/2007/10/upload-file-to-sharepoint-document.html).