# Where to write C# code for office365 sharepoint site

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, sharepoint, office365

I have signed up for office 365
which provides sharepoint site,

I am able to edit the html content of the site.(using Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2010 and Web interface)

Question 1. How to edit the C#/VB code of the site web pages?
Question 2. I have created some asp.net pages and want to upload them to my site, How to use FTP for sharepoint site?
Question 3. How to access data from database for a sharepoint site?

P.S: I have vs2010 but cant open the office365 site ,
also I tried Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2010 but it doesn't display the code behind C#/VB.NET code

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298999/where-is-csharp-source-code-is-used-sharepoint but this doesnt answers, sharepoint has everything in assemblies, then how do we add own assembly in office365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just developed an application for the client. What we did was to setup a virtual environment using VMWare workstation software where we used the following setup:

Microsoft windows 2008 64 bit
VS 2010
Share Point 2010

now while developing applications if you want to setup visual web parts usual visual web parts would not work you have to get an extension for visual web parts(Sandboxed). This extension, not included in visual studio, would give you an option of creating a sandboxed visual web part. You can download it form here:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e602a8c-6714-4549-9e95-f3700344b0d9/

After you create the webpart use the wsp to setup solution on office 365 platform.

You  will have to use a local site to develop and check if the functionality is working.

The database that can be used in office 365 is the SharePoint lists nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just go poking around and do what you want on Office 365 - they don't let you because you can cause problems for the rest of the server.

Instead you have to look at implementing your features as "Sandbox Solutions".

The idea of the sandbox in hosted SharePoint installations is that it restricts the amount of damage (intentional or otherwise) you can do the the rest of the site if your web part does something silly.

[MSDN - Sandboxed Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539083.aspx)

Warning - from your question (e.g. upload .asxp to SharePoint via FTP) its clear that you are very new to SharePoint so you're going to be on a very steep learning curve - start with learning the basics about SharePoint before going onto 365 and sandbox solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Cory Roth has quite a good overview of the steps required to package your code and deploy it to the Office365 SharePoint sandbox:

> [Office 365 How to: Build and Deploy a Web Part with SharePoint Online](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2011/04/01/office-365-how-to-build-and-deploy-a-web-part-with-sharepoint-online.aspx)

In general, you'll need to be deploying packaged features that you can install and run - SharePoint's not really that keen on random editing of .cs/.vb files - you'll need to supply it with a compiled DLL.

---

**Edit to add**

Sadly yes, you need a 64bit operating system to "run" SharePoint 2010 on Windows7:

> [Setting Up the Development Environment for SharePoint 2010 on Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx)

And yes, for development and testing purposes you should indeed have a Local copy of SharePoint - especially when deploying to a Sandbox environment where not everything is available.

Comment: can't develop on my machine - I have vs 2010 on win7 ultimate 32 bit :(

Answer (score 0):

yes you need a local SharePoint installation to start developing for SharePoint / SharePoint Online. To dig into SharePoint development you could use the 14 day free trail from cloudshare.com. Cloudshare is offering cloud hosted SharePoint developer machines.

SharePoint Online development is very similar to SharePoint OnPremise development. There are some limitations. You should have a look at Sandboxed Solutions in SharePoint 2010. There are several video trainings available on channel9 targeting SharePoint development.

Paul Stubbs also published the Easy SharePoint Setup script http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pstubbs/archive/2010/10/27/sharepoint-2010-easy-setup-script.aspx. 
Use this script to automatically setup you SharePoint development box. There is also this great MSDN article describing the setup process and the requirements http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx.

Thorsten