# Does SharePoint Online (Office 365 Cloud) support inline code blocks? SharePoint Designer code view?

Tags: sharepoint, cloud, office365

Will we be able to add .NET code blocks to a page in SharePoint 365 - the cloud version of SharePoint? If so, how do we allow code blocks in the web.config?

Will we be able to use SharePoint designer to customize forms and create dataviews with external datasources?

Can we have asp.net codebehind files and class references? (I suspect not)

Answer (score 4):

.NET code blocks (server-side scripts) are not supported in Office 365. You should build your ASPX page purely from controls and web parts, which would contain the code. Solutions for the SharePoint Online share their [restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615454.aspx) with [sandboxed solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798382.aspx) for SharePoint 2010. The solution scope is a *site collection*; not a web application and thus you cannot access the web.config. However, you may not need to; you're bound only to a single site collection and the most usual task - adding SafeControls - is supported, although the SharePoint engine does not use web.config to maintain them. You can see an example of [deploying a web part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798301.aspx).

You can use the Designer to customize pages, forms and views. External data sources (entity types) - BCS - were [added to SharePoint Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh418045.aspx) by the end of the last year. I haven't checked what connector types are supported; I presume SQL and WS sources, at least.

You cannot have the code-behind in ASPX pages. There is no ASP.NET compilation of pages and user controls available; that's why you have to compose your pages of coded controls and web parts only. However, there is a trick to circumvent this - the [Visual Web Part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh181495). The original visual web part could not be used in a sandboxed solution because it relied on the ASP.NET compilation. There is a template available in [Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e602a8c-6714-4549-9e95-f3700344b0d9) that packages pre-compiled code to the solution and is friendly to the sandbox.

You can develop and test your sandboxed solutions on your local SharePoint 2010 prior deploying them to the SharePoint Online. Although I was surprised that deployng a solution to the SharePoint Online was kind of faster than to my local farm :-) MSVS makes the development really comfortable.

--- Ferda

Answer (score 0):

Not being a .NET developer, here is my limited knowledge. Office 365 is a multi-tenant implementation of SharePoint and you you should have the following capabilities:

- upload code blocks as sandboxed solutions
- ability to customize forms and data views with SharePoint Designer

Note that Office 365 offers 30 day trials that would allow you to test drive it. Let me know if you need more details as there are a couple caveats to be aware of when you start a trial.

Answer (score 0):

This question relates to how to implement what Mr Prantl suggested.

[Where to write C# code for office365 sharepoint site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570612/where-to-write-c-sharp-code-for-office365-sharepoint-site/11734026#11734026)

Hope this helps.